# How to remove the blank line above the table in beamer

Tags: beamer, floats

I want to insert a table in my beamer, but the there's a blank line above the table, how can I remove the blank line to make the table's top align with the text on the right

This is the **MWE**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{How to remove the blank line above the table}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
  \begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
  1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
  1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
  1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    the first line 

    the second line
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and this is the outcome:[image]

Comment: Don't use the table environment. It uses the center environment which inserts a space.

Comment: And if you want your `tabular` centered inside column width, insert `\centering` command before `\begin{tabular}`.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the comments of @UlrikeFischer and @Ignasi to an answer to remove the question from the list of unanswered.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{How to remove the blank line above the table}
\begin{columns}[T]
\begin{column}{.6\textwidth}
    \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
  1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
  1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
  1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    the first line 

    the second line
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]